# Lua iterate over table sorted by values

Tags: sorting, lua, iterator

I have a table `t` with many entries like `t["name1"] = 42`, `t["name2"] = 123`, `...`

I would like to iterate over the table in descending order of the value numbers. How can this be accomplished? I have found methods to create iterator functions that go ordered over the *keys* of a table, but no way to go over the entries with ordered values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pairs_order_by_values_desc(tab)
   local keys = {}
   for k in pairs(tab) do
      keys[#keys + 1] = k
   end
   table.sort(keys, function(a, b) return tab[a] > tab[b] end)
   local j = 0
   return
      function()
         j = j + 1
         local k = keys[j]
         if k ~= nil then
            return k, tab[k]
         end
      end
end

local t = {}
t.name1 = 42
t.name2 = 123
t.name3 = 99

for k, v in pairs_order_by_values_desc(t) do
   print(k, v)
end
```